# Angular: Infinite scroll loading (ajax)

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular-cli

The problem is to implement infinite scroll loading data from JSON file.

I have a service, where have defined a method `getDataFromJson()`. It's method processes data from JSON file, creating custom object, which will be used in the app, and return the array with this custom objects.

`product.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { Product } from '../model/product';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {

  private productsList$: Observable<Product[]>;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.productsList$ = this.getDataFromJson();
  }

  /* Get Data From JSON file */
  getDataFromJson(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('assets/data.json')
      .map((resp: Response) => {
        let prodList = resp.json().product;
        let list: Product[] = [];
        for (let index in prodList) {
          let product = prodList[index].data;
          list.push({
            id: product.id_product,
            category: product.categoryTitle,
            description: product.systemdescription,
            systitle: product.systitle,
            fireresistance: product.fireresistance,
            soundproof: product.soundproof,
            wallthickness: product.wallthickness,
            dampingstrength: product.dampingstrength
          })
        }
        return list;
      })
      .catch((error: any)=> { return Observable.throw(error);});
  }

  getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.productsList$;
  }

}
```

After that, at the `Products Component` I use that method and render my list of products.

`products.component.ts`

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Product} from "../model/product";
import {ProductService} from "../services/product.service";
import {WatchlistService} from "../services/watchlist.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.css']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  public products: Product[] = [];

  constructor(private prodService: ProductService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.prodService.getProducts()
      .subscribe(
        data => this.products = data,
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }

}
```

`products.component.html`

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <app-product-list
      [products]="products"></app-product-list>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <app-product-filters></app-product-filters>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course, all products are rendered at the `Products Component`. But I need that the first time the component is initialized was loaded first 10 products. And after the user has scrolled to the bottom of the screen, the following 5 elements were loaded.

So, сan I implement gradual loading data from array when scrolling and at the same time use the observable approach?
And if it possible, how can I do that? Perhaps, has someone already faced such a problem?